# Same-width lines in multiline text in CSS3

Tags: html, css, multiline

I'm trying to make multiline text the same width using CSS3 and no JavaScript.

To illustrate what I'm looking for, let's take this sentence:

> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.

When displaying this text in a narrow container it breaks across multiple lines like this:

> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and
>
> typesetting industry.

What I'd like to do is have it break something like this:

> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of
>
> the printing and typesetting industry.

The length of each line is almost the same now.

Is this possible using CSS alone? If not, how else would this be possible?

P.S. The text I'd like to be styled this way is not constant, so fixed width solution won't work.

Comment: With css you can only give a certain width to that div and use `word-break` but you will never know how much words are in that sentence so it's not a good choice.

Comment: What determines the width of the container ? Are you talking about making this responsive ?

Comment: @SoorajChandran: It doesn't really matter. It can be its parent or a CSS rule like `width`, `max-width`, etc. The problem is that currently when the maximum width is reached, all the list before last fill up to that width before breaking into another line. Instead I'd like the text to use the same amount of lines as it would normally, but the line breaks to be placed in such a way that the width of each of the lines is roughly the same.

Answer (score 4):

In the future, I would look to using `text-wrap:balance`.

> With `text-wrap: balance` from CSS Text 4, you can request the browser to figure out the best balanced line wrapping solution for the text.

It isn't [widely supported](https://caniuse.com/css-text-wrap-balance) at the time of writing -- there's no Firefox or Safari support as of July 2023.

It's good to know the limitations:

> The task of balancing text is not free. The browser needs to loop over iterations to discover the best balanced wrapping solution. This performance cost is mitigated by a rule, it only works for 4 wrapped lines and under.

and to understand what's happening under the hood:

> The browser effectively performs a binary search for the smallest width which doesn't cause any additional lines, stopping at one CSS pixel (not display pixel). To further minimize steps in the binary search the browser starts with 80% of the average line width.

Quotes from https://developer.chrome.com/blog/css-text-wrap-balance/

Comment: There's also `text-wrap: pretty` if you only want to prevent orphans

Answer (score 1):

This will not be an exact solution. But this is might be the closest you can reach with CSS alone.

You can use `text-align:justify` along with `word-break:keep-all` to make all the lines except the last one take the entire length of the container.

The length of the final line may or may not be close to the length of the container depending on the text.

Using a resizable container to show the same.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#container").resizable();
});
```

```css
#container {
  width: 350px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
  
  text-align:justify;
  word-break:keep-all;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  Etiam sollicitudin, ipsum eu pulvinar rutrum, tellus ipsum laoreet sapien, quis venenatis ante odio sit amet eros. Nullam vel sem. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Phasellus nec sem in justo pellentesque facilisis. Praesent turpis. Cras varius. Proin magna. Mauris sollicitudin fermentum libero. Donec vitae sapien ut libero venenatis faucibus. Cras dapibus.
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but sadly, it's not the solution I'm looking for. It seems that it's not possible with CSS alone. Also, according to MDN, `word-break: keep-all` doesn't affect non-CJK (Chinese/Japanese/Korean) text. At the moment my needs are English text only, so that doesn't make a difference. Also `text-align: justify` doesn't affect the actual number of words in a line, it just affects the spacing between the words in each line, but, as you say, not the last line.

Comment: As for me, it's exactly what I was looking for, thanks !